# Is there a way to add multiple dynamic routes in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

Is there a way to add multiple dynamic routes in angular?

Like this:

```
  {
    path: ':product',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./pages/product/product.module').then((m) => m.ProductModule),
  },
  {
    path: ':category',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./pages/category/category.module').then((m) => m.CategoryModule),
  },
```

Cause If I do the above one of them replaces the other.

Answer (score 1):

To tell Angular whether the path is product or category, you have to write like this.

```
  {
    path: 'product/:product',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./pages/product/product.module').then((m) => m.ProductModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'category/:category',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./pages/category/category.module').then((m) => m.CategoryModule),
  },
```

To access product, `https://(yourserver)/product/(product id)`.
To access category, `https://(yourserver)/category/(category id)`.

Answer (score 0):

Since `:product` and `category` are simply placeholders, Angular doesn't know the difference between them, instead consider the following.

I'd create a path binding for product (to a static path), and then let the module itself do the various bindings, etc.:

In the "root" routing configuration:

```js
{
  path 'products',
  loadChildren: () => 
    import('./pages/product/product.module').then((m) => m.ProductModule),
}
```

... and in the `ProductModule`'s routing:

```js
{
  path: '',
  component: ProductListings,
},
{
  path: ':productId',
  component: ProductDetails,
}
```